# Dividir data obtenido de la base de datos

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, informix

Tengo un problema cuando obtengo la data  de la base de datos, obtengo 4500 filas o más dependiendo de la búsqueda y esta data es distribuida entre 8 personas tratando de ser equitativo.

Esta es la data que obtengo:

[image: Data 1]

La columna importante es `codi_zona` ya que guarda el código de diferentes partes de la ciudad (barrios) y a cada persona se le otorga 2, 3 o 4 zonas dependiendo de la cantidad que salga en la búsqueda por lo cual no puedo darle a una persona que tenga en sus clientes de diferentes zonas ya que no sería posible que visite 20 lugares el mismo dia. Por eso en el ejemplo de arriba muestro con esta sintaxis...

```
select nomb_terc , dire_refe , codi_zona , nuev_terr 
    from x8 
order by codi_zona asc
```

... para que al momento de generar el reporte a la persona se le otorgue clientes de una misma zona.

Pero mi problema radica que no puedo darle a esa misma persona la misma data todos los meses por la cual consulto si habrá una manera de obtener los datos de manera aleatoria, osea:

> Pepe -> codi_zona = 2 , 5 , 8 
>   Mario ->codi_zona = 3,10,21

Lo trabajo asi ahora :

> Pepe -> codi_zona = 1 , 2, 3 
>   Mario ->codi_zona = 4,5,6

... y no de manera ordenada como la estoy trabajando.

Aclaro que las zonas son de manera automática, no las coloco manualmente de acuerdo a la consulta. Puede traer en un mes unas zonas que no se vieron el mes pasado.

Ya intenté con `over (partition)` y no hubo resultados. ¿Hay alguna sintaxis en *informix* que me pueda ayudar a obtener una data así , sin mezclar clientes de diferentes zonas en la data de las personas?

Comment: Admito que no he entendido _casi_ nada. ¿Sería posible explicarte mejor?

Comment: @A.Cedano claro ,Hay 8 gestores de campo que obtienen cartera de clientes por cobrar , cada mes se le asigna una nueva cartera . Codi_zona son como los barrios donde deben ir , no puedo darles  personas de diferentes barrios ya que no se pueden movilizar en un dia de la izquierda a la derecha . Por eso trato de traer de la base de datos de manera ordenada por zona a los clientes y es asi como distribuyo a los gestores.Pero eso no es bueno,por eso ya no quiero que sea de manera ordenada  , si no de manera intercalada o aleatoria sin perder la agrupacion hecha por la columna codi_zona

Comment: ¿que has intentado hasta ahora?

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. lee cómo crear una buena pregunta. Debes editar tu pregunta con el código que hayas intentado, errores, etc. Debes agregar mas código. ¿qué usaste para lograr la funcionalidad que mencionas? edita tu pregunta.

https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour
https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask